# What data structure works best for 2 related lists

Tags: java, data-structures, api-design

I am trying to implement a list of source and target items (which could for example be selected via dropdowns) for a currency exchange calculator, which also needs to change depending on each other.

For e.g. when I select a source currency I would like to change the target list to only supported ones for that source. And also vice-versa, so if I choose a target currency which only may be supported from some sources the source list should change accordingly.

One option I think may be an list of all currencies with each containing a list of supported source and target currencies? Or is there any better approach to implement this?

Comment: What are your currencies? Do you keep them as strings or do you have a class? Some code might be helpful.

Comment: Just use a single `List<Pair<SRC, TGT>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if performance needs to be a consideration here - especially if this for driving GUI elements such as pull-down lists. So I would suggest simplest and most direct is best. Something like:

```
interface Exchange {
    Currency getSource();
    Currency getTarget();
    double getRate();
}

public class Exchanges {
    private final List<Exchange> exchanges = new ArrayList<>();

    public Stream<Currency> getSourcesWithTarget(Currency target) {
        return exchanges.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getTarget().equals(target))
            .map(Exchange::getSource).distinct();
    }

    public Stream<Currency> getTargetsWithSource(Currency source) {
        return exchanges.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getSource().equals(source))
            .map(Exchange::getTarget).distinct();
    }

    public double getRate(Currency source, Currency target) {
        return exchanges.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getSource().equals(source) && e.getTarget().equals(target))
            .map(Exchange::getRate)
            .findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

The `getRate` method is a bonus :-)